# Unix timestamp to Excel datetime

Tags: excel, vba, unix-timestamp

How to convert the Unix timestamp(1662091200) to Windows timestamp format in Excel? VBA code might be helpful.

Comment: Why? Where does the data come from? It may be easier to load the dates as dates. Excel supports dates natively. There's no `Windows timestamp`. Almost all databases and languages support dates natively while JSON and text files use the ISO8601 format, not Unix timestamps.

Comment: `=A1/(60*60*24)+"1/1/1970"`

Comment: Excel can read text/CSV files with ISO8601 date literals. It can load and transform data from many different sources using PowerQuery, even Hadoop or cloud services. That's a lot better and faster than trying to use VBA to convert values cell by cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIX time can be expressed in two ways (10 and 13 digits). Try the next function, able do deal with both cases:

```
Function FromUNIX(uT) As Date
   If Len(uT) = 10 Then
        FromUNIX = DateAdd("s", CDbl(uT), "1/1/1970")
   ElseIf Len(uT) = 13 Then
        FromUNIX = CDbl(uT) / 86400000 + DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)
   Else
        MsgBox "No UNIX timestamp passed to be converted..."
   End If
End Function
```

It can be tested as

```
Sub testFromUnix_()
 Dim x As String, y As String, z As Double
 x = "1637402076084"
 y = "1662091200"
 z = 1662091200
 
 Debug.Print FromUNIX(x)
 Debug.Print FromUNIX(y)
 Debug.Print FromUNIX(y)
End Sub
```

You can use it as UDF:

```
   =FromUNIX(A2)
```

Of course, in A2 should be the UNIX time...

Comment: Be careful with the `Len`-operator. If you use it on a non-string data type (eg a Double or a Long), it will return the number of bytes the data uses (eg 8). I suggest you use the `CStr`-function to convert the parameter into a string.

Comment: @FunThomas What you say is **generally** valid, but try testing the above code declaring `y As Double`. You will have the surprise that it works as it should... It looks that (implicitly) declaring `uT` `As Variant`, VBA correctly guesses what is it about. I was surprised some time ago about this behavior, I confess I do not understand on what mechanism this (pseudo) conversion does it, but I learned that **in such circumstances it works as it's needed**. In fact, I will update the testing sub to also use the same number (from the question) declared `As Double`. Both cases returns correctly...

Comment: @FunThomas  Please, also place `Debug.Print Len(uT)` immediately after `Function FromUNIX(uT) As Date`. You will have the surprise to see it returning 10. :) Even if placing it in the testing sub (as `Debug.Print Len(z)`) returns 8.

Comment: Yeah, just tested, and for some strange reasons it works. Maybe when the `Len` get's a Variant as parameter, it converts it to a String.

Comment: @FunThomas It certainly does something! I discovered this behavior some years before. But I have some doubts that it converts the double to string. You can use it as Double in other circumstances without any problem. It looks that somehow VBA 'understands` what is to be done in case of `Len` using. At least, this was my way of interpreting that time and I do not have anything new to adapt the pseudo theory... :)